# Why is my ASP.NET Core 3.1 controller automatically assigning an ID to an EF Core model that was returned from a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is a bit of a weird one, and I'm 90% sure this is a bug, but you never know.

I'm giving tutoring sessions to students, and I'm trying to get to wrap their heads around using EF Core with ASP.NET Core 3.1. Since they're beginners, I didn't want to jump into writing models for each view that strip out all the EF Core entity data that won't be needed by the view. Instead, I just had them pass the entity model class directly to the view and pass it right back to the controller when they `POST` from the view.

I'm trying to show them how to add a `Comment` to a `Review` entity, but I've run into a weird problem.

Given the following `GET` action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Write([FromRoute] int id)
{
    return View(new Comment
    {
        ReviewId = id
    });
}
```

And the following View:

```
@model Comment
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add a comment";
}
<nav>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Back</a>
</nav>
<h1>ID: @Model.Id</h1>
<form method="post" asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="Write">
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ReviewId)
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Content)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Content)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `Comment`'s ID is automatically set to the last ID in my database, even though it isn't modified by the View or set by the `GET` method, as soon as it reaches my controller's `POST` action.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Write(Comment model)
{
    // Using a debugger, "model" has an ID equal to that of the 
    // last Comment in my database as soon as we enter this method...

    var review = _context.Reviews
                    .Include(r => r.Comments)
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == model.ReviewId);

    if (review != null)
    {
        review.Comments.Add(model);

        _context.Update(review);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // <-- Causes a primary key conflict error because of "model.Id"'s value
    }
}
```

I'm kind of confused by this behavior, but I haven't passed an EF Core model to a controller in forever (we usually write View-specific models that strip out the unneeded data where I work), so maybe this is normal behavior? But it *feels* like a bug to me.

I've found a "fix" for it, by simply explicitly binding what properties I want:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Write([Bind("Content, ReviewId")]Comment model)
```

But I'd like to know **why** the `model`'s `Id` property is automatically set to the last `Comment` entity's `Id` as soon as it hits my controller.

Comment: @GertArnold, I was writing my answer when you first replied to my post. I found the issue. It was because I didn't have `[FromForm]` in my signature, and the framework inferred the model's ID from the URL (I'm guessing because of the `{id?}` bit in the default endpoint route mappings matching the `model.Id` property name?), which had the parent Review's ID (which doesn't change just because we added more Comments). This means that adding more `Comment`s to the same `Review` object eventually clashes with the value of `Review.Id`.

Comment: I suspected something like this could happen, but didn't see how. So *that's* how.

Comment: I never in my life  used  [FromForm] in net core.  But it is usually used only in the special cases where it is needed to point the  source( in the same action some parameters from route, some from query string and some from form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with it further, I've found the source of the problem.

---

The TL;DR:

This fixed my issue.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Write([FromForm]Comment model)
```

---

Explanation:

I completely forgot to add `[FromForm]` to my controller's `POST` action, so the framework wasn't putting the right data in the right field. I'm guessing it was using the `{id?}` portion of the default controller route endpoint mapping and assigning this value to `model.Id`, which caused issues when adding multiple `Comment`s to a `Review`, because the URL's Route `id` value was the parent `Review`'s `Id`, not the `Comment`'s, and this value stays the same when you're adding multiple `Comment`s to a single `Review`.

This means that adding a second `Comment` to the first `Review` object would result in a primary key conflict, because that `Review`'s `Id` was "1", the *first* `Comment`'s `Id` was also "1", and the URL would be `/write/1`, which assigned the second `Comment`'s `Id` to "1", causing the key conflict.

It's also why `model.Id`'s value was seemingly changing as soon as it hit my controller. Because it was. The controller was just using whatever it thought best to get the data from the request, and it was doing it wrong.

I realized something was messing with the bindings when I added a hidden `<input>` tag to make sure that forcefully setting the `Id` to 0 wouldn't solve the issue.

I had added the following line to my view before to make sure my `Id` was set to "0" on the view:

```
<h1>ID: @Model.Id</h1>
```

But the hidden `<input>` tag had a value matching the `Review`'s `Id`, instead of "0". So I went looking into data bindings again, and found this page on MSDN which covered the topic of [Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference), which states that the framework will try to use what it thinks is best when not given an explicit binding source attribute.